# PrimeFaces Input text does not hold any value

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am trying to pass a value to PrimeFaces input text component `<p:inputText/>` but the value is not getting to the bean, the bean is seeing what I passed as null.

XHTML:

```xml
<p:messages id="emessage"  showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" closable="true"/>
<p:panelGrid columns="2" id="viewp">
     <p:outputLabel value="Old Name:"/>
    <p:inputText value="#{editOrderBean.oldMaterialName}"/>
    <p:outputLabel value="New Name:"/>
    <p:inputText value="#{editOrderBean.newMaterialName}"/>
    </p:panelGrid>
     <br/>
<p:commandButton value="Submit" action="{editOrderBean.editOrder}" 
                 ajax="true" update="emessage" immediate="true"/>
```

Bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped

private String oldMaterialName;
private String newMaterialName;

public String getOldMaterialName() {
    return oldMaterialName;
}

public void setOldMaterialName(String oldMaterialName) {
    this.oldMaterialName = oldMaterialName;
}


 public String getNewMaterialName() {
    return newMaterialName;
}

public void setNewMaterialName(String newMaterialName) {
    this.newMaterialName = newMaterialName;
}
```

Comment: Don't use `immediate="true"` if you want to get the form values.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it actually worked when i changed immediate to false. Just that i had to change some required components to false too.